# How to find which columns contain a value in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, grepl, any

I have a large csv dataframe ("mydata") and would need to find if a value ("10295") is in the data frame and at which column. Here are my codes

```
any(mydata==10295) 
which(apply(mydata, 2, function(x) any(grepl("10295", x))))
```

By doing so, I get TRUE at the first request and then get "1,2,5,39" as the columns having the searched value. However if I run

```
any(mydata$col1==10295) #col1 is the index name of column1
```

I get FALSE.
I am sorry if I cannot upload the data but it is a very large dataset. Does anyone have in mind where the mistake could be?

Comment: May be you don't have a fixed match

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I meant with `grepl` you may have a match like 102956 for 10295 while `==` needs the value to be exact 10295

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out columns which have value `10295` in it. You can try with `colSums`.

```
cols <- which(colSums(mydata == 10295, na.rm = TRUE) > 0)
```

`cols` will have column numbers that has at least 1 value of `10295` in it.